# Separar una cadena en Java

Tags: java, android, split

Quiero separar esta cadena para un spinner.

Aca recibo mi JSON lo recorro para solo obtener lo que deseo.

```
JSONObject jsonObject= new JSONObject(responseStrBuilder.toString());
JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("payment_methods");

ArrayList<String> Lista = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
    try {
        JSONObject json = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
        //Aquí se obtiene el dato y es guardado en una lista
        Lista.add(json.get("title").toString());
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

ctOnGo.setMetodosPagos(Lista.toString());
```

> ctOnGo.setMetodosPagos(Lista.toString()); Esto es para guardar lo que
>   me extraje del JSON

El spinner esta aca

```
//Spinner
SpinnerMethod = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_methodopago);
String[] method = {ctPagar.getMetodosPagos()};
ctPagar.getMetodosPagos().split("\\|");
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, method);
SpinnerMethod.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Ahora quiero que esto que guarde {ctPagar.getMetodosPagos()}; se vea asi:

> Check / Money order
>
> PayPal
>
> Pago en la entrega
>
> Pago estandar

Pero me sale es en cadena: **Check / Money order, PayPal, Pago en la entrega, Pago estandar**

Comment: puedes revisas el metodo `split()` del Objeto String, ese te puede servir, solo debes explotar la cadena con las "," Revisa la documentacion: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con esto estarías *hardcodeando* el salto de linea

```
 Lista.add(json.get("title").toString() + "\t\t");
```

Agregado, Solución pasar parametros como ArrayList():

```
new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, ctPagar.getMetodosPagos());
```

Comment: Aun así me sigue apareciendo todo como una cadena, de esto: Check / Money order, PayPal, Pago en la entrega, Pago estandar ... Yo debo seleccionar alguno

Comment: No, sigue sin funcionar...

Comment: Puedes mostrar el codigo de setMetodosPagos() y getMetodosPagos()

Comment: Convertí el setMetodosPagos() y getMetodosPagos() en ArrayList<String> y ahora si los recibo como una lista, pero ahora el problema es para pasarle esa lista al spinner

Comment: new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, ctPagar.getMetodosPagos());

Comment: FUNCIONA. Gracias por tu ayuda